# C++: Overloading the [ ] operator for read and write access

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, operator-overloading

In general, how do you declare the index `[ ]` operator of a class for both read and write accesss?

I tried something like

```
/**
 * Read index operator.
 */
T& operator[](T u);

/**
 * Write index operator
 */
const T& operator[](T u);
```

which gives me the error

```
../src/Class.h:44:14: error: 'const T& Class::operator[](T)' cannot be overloaded
../src/Class.h:39:8: error: with 'T& Class::operator[](T)'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your mutable version is fine:

```
T& operator[](T u);
```

but the `const` version should be a `const` member function as well as returning a `const` reference:

```
const T& operator[](T u) const;
                         ^^^^^
```

This not only distinguishes it from the other overload, but also allows (read-only) access to `const` instances of your class. In general, overloaded member functions can be distinguished by their parameter types and const/volatile qualifications, but *not* by their return types.

Answer (score 8):

You simply have one overload that'll be used for both reads and writes:

```
T& operator[](int);
```

Having said that, you might also want to have a `const` overload:

```
const T& operator[](int) const;
```

This will provide read-only indexing into `const` instances of your class.

Comment: Just to add further explanation, this is because the operator overload returns a reference to the object. This allows you to assign to it as well as read it, hence the need for only one overload.

Answer (score 3):

You get the error, because overloaded functions cannot differ only by return type. But they can differ by const-ness.

```
/**
 * Write index operator.
 */
T& operator[](T u);

/**
 * Read index operator
 */
const T& operator[](T u) const;
```

Note "write" and "read" swapped places.

Also, don't you actually mean the argument of the operator to be some integral type ?