# Overloading subscript operators for specific read and write operations

Tags: c++, overloading, subscript

I'm currently attempting to overload the '[]' operator for both read and write operations.  I have created them like the following:

```
V operator[] (K key) const; //Read
V& operator[] (K key);      //Write
```

However, only the 'write' is called from both the following:

```
foo["test"] = "bar"; //Correct, will use 'write'
cout << foo["test"]; //Incorrect, will use 'write'
```

What is the reason for this and is there a possible solution?

Same question that didn't help, found here: [C++: Overloading the [ ] operator for read and write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686924/c-overloading-the-operator-for-read-and-write-access)

Although, the solution presented did not work as intended, and still only the write overload was accessed.

Comment: Why didn't the other question help? Looks like exactly the same question to me.

Comment: How about `const V& operator[] (K key) const;` instead of `V operator[] (K key) const;`

Comment: It is the same question, but it didn't help since only the write was still accessed

Comment: ***It is the same question, but it didn't help since only the write was still accessed*** You mean write was still accessed after you changed your `V operator[] (K key) const; //Read` to  `const V& operator[] (K key) const; //Read`?

Answer (score 6):

Overloading is done based on the static type of the argument. If the object `foo` you use an operator with is non-`const` the non-`const` overload is used. If it is `const` the `const` overload is used.

If you want to distinguish between reading and writing you'll need to return a proxy from your subscript operator which converts to the suitable type for reading and has a suitable assignment operator for writing:

```
 class X;
 class Proxy {
     X*  object;
     Key key;
 public:
     Proxy(X* object, Key key): object(object), key(key) {}
     operator V() const { return object->read(key); }
     void operator=(V const& v) { object->write(key, v); }
 };
 class X {
     // ...
 public:
     V    read(key) const;
     void write(key, V const& v);
     Proxy operator[](Key key)       { return Proxy(this, key); }
     V     operator[](Key key) const { return this->read(key); }
     // ...
 };
```

Comment: ["Introducing an intermediary proxy may result in surprising compiler errors."](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Temporary_Proxy#Known_Uses). Also there can be [UB if the proxy is constructed from a temporary object and not consumed immediately](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2015/05/21/safer-proxy-idiom/).